# Save Binary Data to an Existing SQL Row

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know how to insert binary data of a `.zip` file into a new SQL Server row into a column of datatype `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

Need help to update existing column of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` of row with binary data from a `.zip` file. Code below works but converting binary to file again renders an defect zip file:

```
byte[] file;

using (var stream = new FileStream(zipFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
    }
}

rowColumn = file;
```

While this works with INSERT with code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@rowColumn", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
```

Comment: If you look at the the hex values of the first 100 bytes or so of the file before and after, how are they different?

Comment: If you want to store **binary** data - you should use a **binary** datatype!! Use `VARBINARY(MAX)` - not `VARCHAR(MAX)` (which is string-based - **NOT** binary!)

Comment: **NVARCHAR(MAX)** is type used in SQL Table, also **SqlDbType.VarBinary** is the working part of code, sorry if I miss something

Comment: Ooh, missed that. Putting binary data in character field is **definitely** gonna mess it up. @marc_s should list that as the answer. But if you can't change the column, the other option is to base-64 encode the bytes before saving them, and base-64 decode the bytes after retrieval.

Comment: tried type change with no success, a piece of code for **updating binary data** or redirecting me to a similar question with accepted solution would be highly appreciated, thanks all the kind people here.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there's a mistake with the column definition. If the database column is `varchar(max)`, you cannot just write binary data there without it getting mangled. There are many different ways to encode character data, but a database column will have a specific format it wants to use so it can know how to do text comparisons and sorting. When load the binary data, it **WILL** re-encode the bytes to match the character encoding on the server.

You have two choices:

1. Change the column type.
2. Base-64 encode the bytes before saving them to column (and update the parameter code to match so it is varchar, instead of varbinary), and then base-64 decode the data again when you retrieve it.

Comment: Storing binary data in a string column is not to be recommended but it will round trip fine. There is no re-encoding if it is just inserted as binary and cast to binary when selected. But of course there is no point doing this as should just use the correct binary datatype

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/Q1U7atme

Comment: Only exception would be that storing an odd number of bytes in an `nvarchar` column will end up giving an extra `0x00` which might be their issue

Comment: @MartinSmith could you add also UPDATE of BLOB please in fiddle tool, thanks.